# How to generate a new privilege key Teamspeak 3

Tags: ubuntu

I just got a new computer and my Teamspeak server doesn't know it's me and won't give me access. I've done a lot of researching everything leading me to sites that tell me to buy this to reset or something similar. I just need to know how to reset my privilege key on Teamspeak 3. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Do you still have access to your old computer (you wrote about a new one)? You can export the identity with the privileges from your old computer and import it on your new one, that way you won't need to change anything

Comment: I have the hard drive from my old computer but I can't get the files off because it takes IDE connectors and my new motherboard doesn't have those. I'm going to be buying an adapter for it soon (or we might even have one, I'd have to look).

Comment: I thought you had your PC in working order, my bad. Well you need to export your identity in TeamSpeak *itself* (this is an actual feature). I don't know whether you can simply copy your TeamSpeak installation over to your new PC (I guess it'll work, though).

Comment: It is working? I just replaced everything but the video card, muchless my old hard drive is PATA and doesn't connect to my new motherboard. I'd have to rebuild my old computer (brother's already took stuff from it) to get the data off.

Comment: Well, that's why you make off-site backups (for the situation when you can't access your data). I recommend simply imaging the drive and pulling all the necessary files from the backup.

Comment: Dude, last time I'll say it. I. Can. Not. Even. Connect. The. Drive. To. A. Working. Computer.